# Can's open SAP HANA Vora Manager 1.3 in the browser

Tags: vora

I'm on the step "2.5.4 Deploy the SAP HANA Vora Services" of Vora 1.3 installation on my HDP 2.3, when I already successfully installed Vora Manager on my . Next thing I try, accordingly to the manual, is open Manager UI at http://:19000 -- that's where it fails

I'm getting an error message "Too many redirects". The same happens when I try to use that URL in wget:

```
--2017-01-19 11:02:30--  http://<masterhost>:19000/
Reusing existing connection to <masterhost>:19000.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: / [following]
```

Could there be anything missing in the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not created an initial password file in your /etc/vora/manager and /etc/vora/datatools directory.

Please follow section 2.5.2 Generate an Initial Password for SAP HANA Vora of the official SAP HANA Vora Installation Guide

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, apparently I forgot to copy it to /etc/vora/manager

Comment: Hi Dimitri, you may want to check Mihail's comment in this thread. Tbh I don't like at all this "hana user file" idea with files to copy around the cluster nodes etc. How about integration with Ambari user management?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://<masterhost>:19000/` will redirect you to `http://<masterhost>:19000/vora-manager/web/`.

If the browser does not follow the redirect, you can either try:

- connect using another browser
- using the incognito-mode of your browser
- clear the browser cache
- check whether JavaScript is enabled in the browser
- disable browser AddOns

Comment: Hmm using /vora-manager/web directly results in Error 404. I've also tried using Chrome in incognito mode and using MSIE to no avail. Provided that everything else works fine in both browsers I tend to think the problem is on the server side.

Comment: I performed `curl http://<masterhost>:19000`, which got me this: `<a href="/">Temporary Redirect</a>.` -- consistent with output of wget in my original post. Leads me to believe the redirect goes to the top rather than to /vora-manager/web, hence the "too many redirects" error.

Answer (score 0):

Works!?! Deleted Vora Manager completelly; restarted server; checked if vora user and group still exist; checked if passwd files on place; reinstalled Vora; restarted server; reconfigured Docker:

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 19001 -j DNAT --to-destination _dockerguestip_:19000
```

Similar story, trying to deploy SAP Vora on Hortonworks Sandbox....
htpasswd is in both directories [datatools,manager] and chowned+chmoded

However it still fails:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# curl http://172.17.0.2:19000
<a href="/vora-manager/web/">Temporary Redirect</a>.
```

and if I try to request the full path I get:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# curl http://172.17.0.2:19000/vora-manager/web
<a href="/vora-manager/web/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

SAP Vora Vers:

```
1.3
```

Sandbox information:

```
Created on: 25_10_2016_08_11_26 for
Hadoop stack version:  Hadoop 2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245
Ambari Version: 2.4.0.0-1225
Ambari Hash: 59175b7aa1ddb74b85551c632e3ce42fed8f0c85
Ambari build:  Release : 1225
Java version:  1.8.0_111
OS Version:  CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
```